# Is there a way to see all questions that have been put on hold as "unclear"?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, on-hold-questions

Is there a way to see all questions that have been put on hold as "unclear"?  (In chronological order with the newest ones first?

Comment: My best bet would be data explorer.

Comment: Michael, just in case you missed it, here is a [somewhat related ongoing discussion](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/23649/11619).

Comment: Are we going to see a wave of robo-reopening votes?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi : ha ha ha.   "Robo" is something I've expressed objections to. $\qquad$

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I suppose it is most likely connected with the effort to collect examples of posts that were closed but the OP thinks they should not have been. At least that seems to be a reasonable guess [based on this comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/23687/responding-to-imperfectly-phrased-questions#comment95347_23687).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/415563/questions-closed-as-unclear

You can sort by creation date.

Comment: Of course, this should come with the usual warning that the data in [data explorer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info) are updated [once a week](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145697/when-will-data-se-get-updated-data).